# Is there a way to refer a variable when the variable name has a number in it

Tags: r

In the following assignment : assign(paste("orca", i, sep = ""), list_name[[i]]), the variable name contains number based on the value of i. Now if I want to perform an operation on say orca1, orca2 till orcan. How do I refer it using a variable(i) once again.

```
x <- 1
y <- 0
for (i in 1:10)
{
  x <- x*0.8
  y <- y + x*orca'i'
}
```

I want to achieve the following:

y = 0.8 * orca1 + 0.8^2 * orca2 + 0.8^3 * orca3 +..+ 0.8^10 * orca10

How do I do it?
Is there any other way to do this as well

Edit: I have tried using a list as follows as I heard it is a more appropriate way to use as follows:

```
x <- seq(1:50)
y <- 1
orcasum <- 0
orca <- list()
for(i in 1:10)
{
  y <- y*0.8
  orca[i] <- y*lag(x,i)
  orcasum <- orcasum + orca[i]
}
```

I tried the above code to achieve the same expected result as earlier. The problem I faced here is: "In orca[i] <- y*lag(x,i) : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".

How do I proceed now?

Comment: How the objects `orca1` ... `orca10` are generated? It is better to use a list than to generate a bunch of objects.

Comment: @jogo is right. Though to achieve `orca'i'` you could use `get(paste0("orca", i))`

Comment: @jogo As you said I tried using a list as follows
orca <- list()
orca[1] <- seq(1:10);

Then I faced this issue on  executing the second line: "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

How do I do it as you say?

Comment: @Aurèle Thanks, it works. For now I can use this. But even I feel this is not up to the standards for performing the required task. So If any of you know what would be the proper approach for my problem, it will be really helpful if you could share them. Thanks in advance

Comment: @jogo I tried assigning orca[1] with seq(1:50), then orca[2] with lag(orca[1],1), orca[3] with lag(orca[2],1) and so on till orca [10]. Then I want to achieve this : y = 0.8 * orca[1] + 0.8^2 * orca[2] + 0.8^3 * orca[3] +..+ 0.8^10 * orca[10]

Comment: @jogo I have edited my problem statement. Is it fine?

Comment: It should be `orca[[i]] <- y*lag(x,i)`and `orcasum <- orcasum + orca[[i]]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short version using a matrix:

```
x <- seq(1:50)
orca <- matrix(NA, 50, 10)
for (i in 1:10) orca[, i] <- lag(x,i)

orcasum <- orca %*% (0.8^(1:10))
```

or generating the matrix `orca` with `sapply()`

```
x <- seq(1:50)
orca <- sapply(1:10, FUN=lag, x=x)
orcasum <- orca %*% (0.8^(1:10))
```